# GTX 760 for a 1366x768 Monitor?

Tags: display, gpu

I want to buy a good GPU for playing AC:Origin, Monster Hunter World, Forza something on my 1366x768 monitor. I haven't played any of the game said above or any game released on the past 9-10 years due to my Intel HD. All i wanna know is is a GTX 750ti capable for high settings or should i buy the little costlier GTX 760? I saw some benchmark and gameplay on Youtube but all of them were 1080p!

Comment: "I wanna know it is a GTX 750ti capable for high settings" - No; You will be unable to play any of those games on high using a GTX 750 Ti.  Since you have a 9-year-old processor, it is doubtful, any of those applications will even run.  AC: Origin barely runs on my i7 4770k and GTX 770.

Answer (score 1):

The GTX 700 series was released in 2013 -- these graphics cards are 5-6 years old. They will likely struggle to run new video games *at all*, let alone on high settings.

These cards might be a sensible upgrade if you could get them at no cost, but they are not worth spending money on. If you want to spend money on a graphics card, buy something more recent.